# How can i check only memory from tasklist cmd

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2012-r2

In windoes cmd when i'm invoking tasklist command filtered by specific process i get all the information about the process (id/name/memory..)

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq someprocess.exe" /fo list
```

the result i get:

> Image Name:   someprocess.exe
>   PID:          1111
>   Session Name: Services
>   Session#:     0
>   Mem Usage:    2,456 K

My question how can i select only the memory and from all that table i will get

> Mem Usage: 2,456 K

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq someprocess.exe" /fo list |find "Mem Usage"
```